# How to create a reference from one class passed to anoher?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, properties

I have a NSMutableArray (called listOfSites) that is created and used in classA.m.  I want to reference that same instance from classB.m so I get the current contents of listOfSites.  I understand I need to create a reference in classA which classB can then reference.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Does classB have access to that instance of classA?

Comment: No... that's the problem... "not defined"... so that's the reason for the reference. (they are in the same project, just different classes)

Comment: What is the relationship between `class A` and `class B`?  The range of solutions is related to the relationship that exists between the classes that need to 'know about' the `NSMutableArray` instance in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up using a singleton, which does the job very well... .thank you both for your time and responses.

Answer (score 2):

Is the listOfSites an instance property or a class property?  If it's an instance, I would suggest defining a property and then synthesizing the getters/setters.  So, for example:

```
@interface classA
   @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listOfSites;
@end

@implementation classA
   @synthesize listOfSites;
@end
```

Then, in classB, perhaps you have a reference to the instance of classA, called myClassA.  Then you can grab it by just stating:

```
NSMutableArray *siteList = myClassA.listOfSites;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things here. Firstly it is not a good idea to use lowercase letters at the start of class names because that is how we code variable names. So `classA` should be `ClassA'.

Next you have to decide how you classes should relate to each other. There are two obvious options:

1. ClassB has a reference to ClassA so that when it needs the list it can ask ClassA for it.
2. Both ClassA and ClassB have a reference to a list, which they both share. In this case there is no need for references between them. Usually a third class is involved.

Which of these designs you choose will depend on what your program needs to do.